# json.loads() giving exception that it expects a value, looks like value is there

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unicode

Code:

```
loaded_json = json.loads(json_set)
```

`json_set` is a String gleaned from a webpage which is JSON formatted data. The full String (warning: LONG) is here: http://pastebin.com/wykwNEeg

There error it gives me (if I save the string to its own file and `readlines` + `json.loads` that line in IDLE) is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 62233 (char 62232)
```

---

```
","distance":\u002d1,"lo
            ^(gedit tells me column 62233 lies between the colon and the \
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the unicode, this particular one being unicode for `-`, so that value should be `"distance":-1`

What's strange is that if I print the line out when I hit the exception (or wherever, I guess) it comes out as above. However if I open up a python3 IDLE session and do this, I get different results:

```
>>> mystr = '"distance":\u002d1'
>>> mystr
'"distance":-1'
>>> print(mystr)
"distance":-1
>>>
```

How do I get this JSON to load properly?

===============

This data comes earlier on from code that looks like so (basically showing that the string is a result of `response.decode('utf8')`):

```
'''This bit gets the page from the website, it's called from the below code block'''
def load_arbitrary_page(self, url):
    response = self.opener.open(url)
    response_list = response.readlines()
    decode_list = []
    for line in response_list:
        decode = line.decode('utf8')
        decode_list.append(decode)  

    print(BeautifulSoup(''.join(decode_list)).find("title"))

    return decode_list
```

---

```
    html = grabber.load_arbitrary_page(url)
    count+=1
    for line in html:
        #Appears to show up 3 times, all in the same line
        if "<my search parameter>" in line:
            content_list.append(line)
            break
```

Finally, the `content_list` is split on comments (`re.split("<!-- ...`) and the final portion of that becomes the variable `json_set`.

Comment: you are scraping LinkedIn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [ECMA-404 standard for JSON](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), you'll see that numbers may have an optional leading minus sign which they designate as [U+002D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) which is the ASCII minus sign. However, `\u002D` is not a minus sign. It is a character escape for a minus sign, but character escapes are only valid in the context of a string value. But string values *must* start and end with double quotes, so this is not a string value. Thus the data you have does not parse as a valid JSON value, and the Python JSON parser is correct in rejecting it.

If you try validating that data blob using the http://jsonlint.com/ website, it will also report that the data is not valid JSON.

```
Parse error on line 2172:
...        "distance": \u002d1,           
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

The example you give with IDLE working is not an equal comparison because the string you gave is different:

```
'"distance":\u002d1' != '"distance":\\u002d1'
```

The string on the left is the string you gave IDLE and if you enclosed it in curly braces, it would be valid JSON:

```
>>> json.loads('{"distance":\u002d1}')
{'distance': -1}
```

But if you give it the string on the right, you'll see that it will not work as you expect:

```
>>> json.loads('{"distance":\\u002d1}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/json/decoder.py", line 367, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/json/__init__.py", line 309, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/json/decoder.py", line 351, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/json/decoder.py", line 369, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: so then, when I print it I'm getting `\u002d1` out which means that the literal string is `\\u002d1`. If I went through and did an `re.sub('\\\\u002d1','-1',mystr)` I would probably get something useful out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do there with that `re.sub` invocation. You're missing an argument. Also, there's only one backslash in the data, so you wouldn't need to escape it twice, that will simply not find anything. You are misunderstanding the difference between the visual representation of the string and it's actual storage representation.

Comment: Maybe you mean this: `re.sub(r'\\u002D', '-', mystr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`. You could do that as a preprocessing step, but technically, you're no longer treating the string as JSON data. If you just want to get the data out and you don't care about it validating, then yes, that will probably work.

Comment: It ended up working using `(json_set, n) = re.subn('"distance":\\\\u002d1', '"distance":-1', json_set )`. For some reason, using just `sub` wasn't working (though now that I think about it I'm unsure if sub returns a new string or changes the string you send in). Luckily this is a field I don't actually care about, so I don't care about invalidating it.