# Nested data to csv python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a file of nested json data. I am trying to "get.some_object" and write a csv file with the objects (I think they are called objects: "some_object": "some_value"); I would like one row for each group of nested items. This is my code:

```
import csv
import json

path = 'E:/Uni Arbeit/Prof Hayo/Sascha/Bill data/97/bills/hr/hr4242'

outputfile = open('TaxLaw1981.csv', 'w', newline='')                            
outputwriter = csv.writer(outputfile)

with open(path + "/" + "/data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for act in data['actions']:
        a = act.get('acted_at')
        b = act.get('text')
        c = act.get('type')

        outputwriter.writerow([a, b, c])
outputfile.close()
```

The problem I have is that it only writes the last group of data to csv; however when I run

```
with open(path + "/" + "/data.json", "r") as f:
data = json.load(f)

for act in data['actions']:

    a = act.get('acted_at')
    b = act.get('text')
    c = act.get('type')
    print (a)
```

all of my "a" values print out.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush your **outputwriter** to write the row to the file, else it will keep on replacing the one in the variable and eventually only write the last value. Writerow only works when you close the file unless you flush the data.

```
for act in data['actions']:
        a = act.get('acted_at')
        b = act.get('text')
        c = act.get('type')
        outputwriter.writerow([a, b, c])
        outputfile.flush()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Uni Arbeit\Prof Hayo\Sascha\code for parsing senate data .py", line 31, in <module>
    outputwriter.flush()
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'flush'

Comment: So sorry for that, you need to do a outputfile.flush() , editing answer.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a json read failure, not sure. Are you sure that file exists at the path or have you changed the permission from 'r' to 'w'?

Comment: I changed it from "r" to "wb" and got the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Uni Arbeit\Prof Hayo\Sascha\code for parsing senate data .py", line 10, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
io.UnsupportedOperation: read

Comment: when I use "r" I get a very long error, the one I posted earlier and already deleated.

Comment: I think its still a json file problem. Have a look at this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270668/json-loads-giving-exception-that-it-expects-a-value-looks-like-value-is-there

Comment: No need to flush. `writerow` already writes to a new row each time

Comment: @ishaan, it was a json file problem, and I have no idea why but when I was using the code above, after the first time all of the data was erasing from the file. I went ahead and downloaded it again and used my original code and now it works fine. I have no idea why or how

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, if its working, you don't question it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted above works 100% with the file you have.

The file (for anyone interested) is available with `rsync -avz --delete --delete-excluded --exclude **/text-versions/ govtrack.us::govtrackdata/congress/97/bills/hr/hr4242 .`
.

And the output to the csv file is (omitting some lines in the middle)

```
1981-07-23,Referred to House Committee on Ways and Means.,referral
1981-07-23,"Consideration and Mark-up Session Held by Committee on Ways and Means Prior to Introduction (Jun 10, 81 through Jul 23, 81).",action
1981-07-23,"Hearings Held by House Committee on Ways and Means Prior to Introduction (Feb 24, 25, Mar 3, 4, 5, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 31, Apr 1, 2, 3, 7, 81).",action
...
...
...
1981-08-12,Measure Signed in Senate.,action
1981-08-12,Presented to President.,topresident
1981-08-13,Signed by President.,signed
1981-08-13,Became Public Law No: 97-34.,enacted
```

You should post the full error code you get when you execute (probably due to an encoding error) to let someone understand why your code is failing.

Comment: For some reason, something in my code was erasing the whole file so that when I ran the code twice, there was no code to run it on. I just used my original code now, and it works. This is too bizarre for me to understand

Comment: Swapping `r` for `w` as you mentioned in one of your comments may have helped